# wordpress addthis plugin causing extra chars on home page excerpt

Tags: wordpress, addthis

I am using wordpress WordPress 4.1.1 with Hueman Theme Version: 1.5.4. When I installed and configured AddThis for WordPress plugin Version 4.0.7. I started seeing

```
+-*
```

in the beginning of every post excerpt on home page of my website. On post page everything seems fine. Not sure what to do. When I disable the plugin it goes of but when I enable it again it comes back. website: [fossbytes.com](http://fossbytes.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin is not rendering the share buttons correctly (under the excerpt). For a quick fix install an older version https://wordpress.org/plugins/addthis/developers/

4.0.3 has corrected the issue for me.